# Detection of VoLTE call in android

Tags: android, lte

I have a very minimal knowledge about VoLTE service in android which is provided by the LTE operator.

Is there any API's are available to detect VoLTE call in android?

The API's such as

- Call Connected
- Call Disconnected
- Latency
- Call Status

Any link/API reference is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`TelephonyManager.java` have a function to check `isVolteAvailable()`. You can call that function to know the status of voLTE.

You can check the source here.. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java

Comment: Thanks. I have checked it.I think it will not trigger the function `onCallStateChanged` when voLTE call connect.

Comment: Hello hav you Found Solution For get voLTE call detection and get more details about it ...

Comment: isVolteAvailable() is not resolve i am using 24.0 app supports pls reply

Comment: Any body found solution on this?

Comment: The linked code for `isVolteAvailable()` is annotated with `@UnsupportedAppUsage` meaning it is not intended for use by end users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499754/what-does-unsupportedappusage-annotation-depict

Comment: isVolteAvailable() method doing a violation of security in Android 10 and above. So is there any other solution is available?

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to at port then by using standard at commands, this can be verified.

1. at+cops?  => this will give information about the current latched cell. check if the mobile is currently on LTE(7) cell.
2. make volte call and shoot the at+cops? again. If the call is connected and mobile is still in LTE(7) cell, then its for sure VoLTE call.