# HitRect returning wrong Y value for unknown reason

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml, android-touch-event

I am creating a pixel art app, which has the following layout:

[image]

Input events are detected inside the pixel art board, meaning that if the user swipes from the root layout and travels their finger inside the pixel art board, it doesn't detect it. This is obviously a minor issue.

To fix this, I looked online and I found the following code which kind of fixed the problem:

```
binding.root.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
    val hitRect = Rect()
    binding.activityCanvasCardView.getHitRect(hitRect)

    if (hitRect.contains(motionEvent.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())) {
        Log.d("LOG123", "Hi ${motionEvent.xPrecision} ${motionEvent.yPrecision}")

        binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    }
    true
}
```

Note that the view coordinates are converted into pixel coordinates in the `onTouchEvent` method.

Simple enough, right? In a perfect world, that code should fix the issue.

There's only one problem, for some reason, there is an offset with the y value:

[image]

I am unsure why I am having this strange delay with the Y coordinates.

I've tried to fix this issue, some of the things I tried were:

- manually applying offset values
- using different rect functions of the `View` class
- look online to see if anyone has a similar issue

I'm following things by the book.

---

I tried the code that Sergei Kozelko gave me, I don't know if it's because I'm scaling/sizing the view in `onCreate`, but the code isn't working:

[image]

Code I tried:

```
binding.root.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
val hitRect = Rect()
binding.activityCanvasCardView.getHitRect(hitRect)

if (hitRect.contains(motionEvent.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())) {
    val offsetX = motionEvent.x - binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView.left
    val offsetY = motionEvent.y - binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView.top

    motionEvent.offsetLocation(offsetX, offsetY)
    val inverseCopy = Matrix()

    if (!binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView.matrix.isIdentity) {
        binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView.matrix.invert(inverseCopy)
        motionEvent.transform(inverseCopy)
    }

    binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
}
true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are calling `activityCanvasPixelGridView.onTouchEvent` with unmodified parent event. The coordinates are in parent's coordinate space while `onTouchEvent` expects them to be in this view's coordinate space.

Android does this automatically in [`ViewGroup#dispatchTransformedTouchEvent`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java;drc=b23c8c8e87972380cdf77e6bacbf9ae608ebcf40;l=3079):

```
final float offsetX = mScrollX - child.mLeft;
final float offsetY = mScrollY - child.mTop;
transformedEvent.offsetLocation(offsetX, offsetY);
if (! child.hasIdentityMatrix()) {
    transformedEvent.transform(child.getInverseMatrix());
}

handled = child.dispatchTouchEvent(transformedEvent);
```

There is also [`getTransformedMotionEvent`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java;drc=2861b20eb1eba9c76b524c00237295dd4f6623a3;l=2609) which just transforms the event but it is marked private. So you'll have to reimplement it yourself. The only non-straightforward moment is dealing with transformation, as both `hasIdentityMatrix` and `getInverseMatrix` are marked with `@UnsupportedAppUsage` and [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499754/what-does-unsupportedappusage-annotation-depict). Instead you'll need to use [`Matrix#isIdentity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix?hl=en#isIdentity()) and [`Matrix#invert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix?hl=en#invert(android.graphics.Matrix)) which do the same calculations, just [with more overhead](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/RenderNode.java;drc=2861b20eb1eba9c76b524c00237295dd4f6623a3;l=497).

Combined together it looks like this:

```
binding.root.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
val hitRect = Rect()
binding.activityCanvasCardView.getHitRect(hitRect)

if (hitRect.contains(motionEvent.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())) {
    val parent = binding.root
    val child = binding.activityCanvasCardView
    val offsetX = parent.scrollX - child.left
    val offsetY = parent.scrollY - child.top

    motionEvent.offsetLocation(offsetX, offsetY)
    val inverseCopy = Matrix()

    if (!child.matrix.isIdentity) {
        child.matrix.invert(inverseCopy)
        motionEvent.transform(inverseCopy)
    }

    child.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
}
true
}
```

Now, all this works only if `child` (`activityCanvasCardView`) is a direct child of `parent` (`root`). If it is not you'll need to apply the above transformation for every view between them. Again, there is nothing in Android that does exactly what you need, the closest thing is [`ViewGroup#offsetRectIntoDescendantCoords`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#offsetRectIntoDescendantCoords(android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect)). But it operates on `Rect`s and doesn't account for transformations. And again you can implement it yourself like this:

```
private fun transformToChild(parent: View, child: View, event: MotionEvent) {
    val offsetX = parent.scrollX - child.left;
    val offsetY = parent.scrollY - child.top;
    event.offsetLocation(offsetX.toFloat(), offsetY.toFloat());
    if (!child.matrix.isIdentity) {
        val inverse = Matrix()
        child.matrix.invert(inverse)
        event.transform(inverse);
    }
}

private fun transformToDescendant(parent: View, descendant: View, event: MotionEvent) {
    if (parent == descendant) {
        return
    }

    var currentDescendant = descendant
    val stack = mutableListOf<View>()
    while (currentDescendant != parent) {
        stack.add(currentDescendant)
        // safe to cast to View as parent function argument is View
        currentDescendant = currentDescendant.parent as View
    }

    for (view in stack.asReversed()) {
        transformToChild(view.parent as View, view, event)
    }
}
```

and call like `transformToDescendant(binding.root, binding.activityCanvasPixelGridView, event)` inside `setOnTouchListener`.

Please note that this code was not properly tested, throws `ClassCastException` if `descendant` is not actually a descendant of `parent` and maybe could be optimized better to remove list. However it should work, or at least give you general idea how to implement it yourself.

Finally, this doesn't happen on X axis because the canvas fills full width, so the X coordinates in parent and child views are the same.

Comment: What is `mScrollX` and `mScrollY`?

Comment: How do I access the `isIdentity` and `invert` functions? What type is `child`?

Comment: What is the `handled` variable? There are many things unclear with your answer... Please edit or explain.

Comment: I have attached a video showing the result of your code.

Comment: I've updated the answer with full solution code. `handled` stores if the event was handled by the child or if we need to continue dispatch. Honestly, describing everything that happens during event dispatch deserves its own Q/A.

Comment: I will try out your code. Just for the effort you've spent in your answer -- I will give you the bounty.

Comment: It WORKS! Thank you dude. For the last year or so I've yearned for a solution to this issue I had in which my app wasn't detecting touch events outside the canvas, and my users were complaining about this issue frequently. You're amazing. I will give you full attribution in my code for this.