# VideoEncoderCap is it deprecated in Android 13?

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm working on Camera Apps using Android 13 API. However, when I tried to obtain the `maxFrameWidth` and `maxFrameHeight` of each supported video encoders such as MPEG4, H263 and so on, VideoEncoderCap is not able to call. I wonder is it deprecated in Android 13 ?

I set `mintargetSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 30, seems not working too.

The reason why I want to use VideoEncoderCap because the `maxFrameWidth` and `maxFrameHeight` obtained through `MediaCodecInfo (getSupportedHeights().getUpper())` is different compare to VideoEncoderCap.

Any advice are welcome.

Comment: Based on: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r45/media/java/android/media/EncoderCapabilities.java the entire class has the [@hide annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31908205/295004) and if you checked [Android 12 version of that file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android12-release/media/java/android/media/EncoderCapabilities.java) those fields you are interested in where marked with [@UnsupportedAppUsage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52499754/295004)

Comment: @Morrison Chang, so it's not recommended to use in Android 13 ? 
Is there any other method to access same dimensions with other API ?

So far I tested `MediaCodecInfo` `MediaCodecList` , the output is different.

Comment: @Morrison Chang, I compared both links you shared, it seems like both classes from the both links are marked with `@unsuportedAppUsage` , I don't see the `@hide` annototation except the one in the commented code.

Comment: Somehow missed the both have the [@hide annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17035271/295004). Details/use case as to why you are accessing `VideoEncoderCap` fields might be helpful. Found this issue which may be related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224990734

Comment: @Morrison Chang, I'm accessing those parameters to calculate the max frame width / max frame height of video encoder.