# How to check VoLTE enabled programmatically

Tags: android

I really need help here.

I'm building a call App for replacing the default one. The App needs to know SIM settings such as carrier name, slot number, etc.
Unfortunately, I'm able to get most of the info but the VoLTE setting.

I found my mobile default call App knows the SIM VoLTE is enabled or not in three case

1. Displaying icon on [call button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2gZg.jpg)
2. Displaying icon during the in-call UI
3. Displaying icon on the call logs which call with VoLTE

Anyone knows how can I get the status of the VoLTE setting?

Thanks!

Here is some reference during my research
SubscriptionManager, TelecomManager, TelephonyManager, InCallService, CarrierConfigManager
[Detection of VoLTE call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224263/detection-of-volte-call-in-android)
(and many unrelated stuff...........)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detection of VoLTE call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224263/detection-of-volte-call-in-android)

Comment: I think that _answer_ is addressing this question, but it's not a good answer to the question that was asked, so I'm disinclined to mark it as a duplicate.